# What's "Faulting" Behavior?

Tags: ios, core-data, fault

Could anyone please explain the meaning of "fault" for me?

Here is the documentation of "Faulting Behavior" from Core Data Performance Doc by Apple.

> Faulting Behavior
>
> Firing faults can be a comparatively expensive process (potentially requiring a round trip to the persistent store), and you may wish to avoid unnecessarily firing a fault. You can safely invoke the following methods on a fault without causing it to fire: isEqual:, hash, superclass, class, self, zone, isProxy,isKindOfClass:, isMemberOfClass:, conformsToProtocol:, respondsToSelector:, description, managedObjectContext, entity, objectID, isInserted, isUpdated, isDeleted, and isFault.
>
> Since isEqual and hash do not cause a fault to fire, managed objects can typically be placed in collections without firing a fault. Note, however, that invoking key-value coding methods on the collection object might in turn result in an invocation of valueForKey: on a managed object, which would fire a fault. In addition, although the default implementation of description does not cause a fault to fire, if you implement a custom description method that accesses the object’s persistent properties, this will cause a fault to fire.
>
> Note that just because a managed object is a fault, it does not necessarily mean that the data for the object are not in memory—see the definition for isFault.

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you understand it to mean? What specifically doesn't make sense?

Comment: I don't understand what's "fault" means...

Comment: [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

Comment: Since I had no database background this totally stumped me for the longest time. The best way I can describe it is, suppose you ask the system for a NSDictionary - it returns a bunch of key value pairs. Then, unknown to you, the system needs memory and takes back all the values - the keys are still their but the values are nil. This is a "fault". Later, when you ask the dictionary for the value of some key, it has to block you for a bit while it goes to an external source and fetches the data for that key again. In fact, you can tell the MOC to "fault" objects for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms, a `fault` is a description of the situation where you have a reference to some data but that data isn't actually in memory (so it isn't immediately available and will need to be fetched from somewhere else).

So, you have a managed object instance, but you can only call a few methods on it without causing additional data to be collected and loaded into memory.